# Search for a word and if occurs, delete it and move to the end of line

Tags: search

I need to search for a certain word, and if it occurs, move it to the end of the line where it occured. For instance, search for "bugs".

Welcome! Meta Stack Exchange is intended for bugs, features, and discussions

Turns into:

Welcome! Meta Stack Exchange is intended for, features, and discussions bugs

Answer (score 2):

```
:g/ \?\<bugs\>/normal! dgn$p
```

Explanation:

`:g/.../` for all lines matching a pattern

`\?\<bugs\>` an optional space followed by "bugs" (a whole word)

`normal! dgn$p` delete last match; go to end of line; put last match there

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`:substitute`](https://www.vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#%3Asubstitute) command for this:

```
:%s/\v ?(<bugs>)(.*)/\2 \1
```

- `:%s` substitute
- `/` start of regular expression
- `\v` use [very magic](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%2Fmagic) mode. This makes this regular expression a bit easier to read/write, because you don't need to use so many backslashes
- `[SPACE]?` an [optional](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5C%3F) space
- `(<bugs>)` find the entire word bugs, and save it in capture group 1. The angle brackets `<>` mark the [start and end of a word](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5C%3C). The parentheses `()` mark the start and end of a [capture group](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5C%28)
- `(.*)` find anything that follows, and save it in capture group 2
- `/` end of regular expression
- `\2 \1` replace the matched text with the contents of capture group 2, followed by a space, followed by the contents of capture group 1